# How do I continue a mercurial merge

Tags: merge, mercurial

I've spent the last few hours doing an enormous merge in mercurial.  After 131 files merged, my merge tool, meld, crashed showing a python traceback.  Trying to quit meld, I've inadvertently also quit out of the mercurial merge.

I'd quite like to just continue the merge from where I left off, e.g. something like `hg merge --continue` but I can't find an option to do that.

If I re-run `hg merge` it warns about uncommitted outstanding changes.  `hg resolve` doesn't list anything to resolve, but I am most likely only about 60% of the way through the merge.

Is there a command to continue the merge from where I was?

Comment: Did you have conflicts?  You shouldn't have to do anything (other than commit the merge) unless you have conflicts.

Comment: Yes, that is 131 files with conflicts merged so far!  This is a merge of approximately two years worth of development where each team has gone in different directions to some extent.

Comment: It appears that the default merge uses a tool rather than inserting conflict markers.  I recommend you ask on the [mailing list](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MailingLists).  That's where all the gurus hang out.

Comment: Do you want to start over from a fresh point, or do you want to save the current status?

Comment: hg merge *does not commit*. After hg merge (and possible conflict resolutions) you still have to call `hg commit`

Answer (score 11):

In TortoiseHg:

1. [Select all files which are still marked as conflicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po2af.png)
2. [Right-click on the files, and select "Restart merge"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyrN1.png)
3. Resolve the files
4. Commit the change

From command line:

1. `hg resolve --all` (continue the merge with all files that are still marked as conflicted)
2. Resolve the files
3. `hg commit` (commit the change)

`hg resolve` does nothing. To list files which have outstanding conflicts, use `hg resolve --list`. (The prefix `U` means that the file is unresolved, `R` is resolved.)